# Cross-platforms WPF application with WebBrowser

Tags: javascript, wpf

I'm looking for the best way to develop a cross-platforms (Windows, IOS, Android) WPF application with only an embedded WebBrowser. It should load a HTML/Javascript page and allow communication between JavaScript and C#, in both side.

I can use Xamarin, with a "web browser object" for each OS. So the communication C# -> JavaScript can be implemented differently for each OS.

However, the communication JavaScript -> C# should stay the same. How can I use c# methods without using "window.external" (Specific to WPF WebBrowser) ? Is it possible to do it without using any framework like PhoneGap ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"WPF" Is the acronym for *Windows Presentation Foundation*, a technology which is part of the .Net Framework and which is built upon core Windows components such as DirectX.

It does NOT work in any other platforms except Windows (the Full, Desktop Version of Windows). It doesn't even run in the RT version of Windows that you can find in portable devices such as Tablets.

If you need a cross-platform app, either use web technologies (HTML + JavaScript) or use a product like Xamarin to build native apps on different platforms while sharing common code (application logic, data access, etc).

WPF is NOT cross-platform.

Comment: Yes, I will use Xamarin, the WPF app is for the Windows part for now, sorry. I'm still looking for a way to call C# from JavaScript in an ambedded Web Browser